# time data "STR" does not match format '%H:%M:%S'

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to import and visualize data from an Excel sheet using Pandas and Matplotlib.

The data file is in ISO 8601 with 4 Hz. What I want to do is show the x-axis with only HH:MM:SS and a lower tick rate, 30-60 seconds.

I managed to convert from ISO 8601 to HH:MM:SS with the following:

```
data["Time UTC"] = [element[10:19] for element in data["Time_4Hz"]]
```

Then I want to define the left and right range as follows:

```
for element in data.index:
    x_limit_l = min(datetime.strptime(element, '%H:%M:%S'))
    x_limit_r = max(datetime.strptime(element, '%H:%M:%S'))
```

and get the following error:

```
ValueError: time data ' 08:45:27' does not match format '%H:%M:%S'
```

The time should be a string with the correct format, what could be the reason for the error?

I tried looping through the "Time UTC" colum with:

```
for element in data.index:
    x_limit_l = min(datetime.strptime(element, '%H:%M:%S'))
    x_limit_r = max(datetime.strptime(element, '%H:%M:%S'))
```

I also tried getting the time directly from the column with:

```
    x_limit_l = min(datetime.strptime("data.index", '%H:%M:%S'))
    x_limit_r = max(datetime.strptime("data.index", '%H:%M:%S'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should it not be data["Time UTC"] = [element[11:19] for element in data["Time_4Hz"]]?

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
lst = ['2022-12-06 12:42:40Z','2022-12-06 12:44:40Z','2022-12-06 12:46:40Z','2022-12-06 12:48:40Z']
data = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns =['Time_4Hz'])
data["Time UTC"] = [element[11:19] for element in data["Time_4Hz"]]
x_limit_l = print(max(data["Time UTC"]))
x_limit_r = print(min(data["Time UTC"]))
print(x_limit_l, x_limit_r)
```

No need to loop

Comment: You are right, it works as well. I initially attempted in in a similar fashion but screwed up somewhere else I guess...Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there are spaces in the `str` which raises the `Exception`. To fix that, you can use `strip` function. If you don't know about it, it just removes spaces from start and end of `str`.

```py
x_limit_l = datetime.strptime(element.strip(), '%H:%M:%S')
```

EDIT: For the error you are getting after implementing, there's no use of using `min` in a single value excluding the fact that `datetime` object cannot be iterable.

Here's a working work-around, assuming you can apply logic yourself:

```py
x_limit_list = list() #Creates a list

for element in data.index:
    #Just showing of one element
    x_limit_l = x_limit_list.append(datetime.strptime(element, '%H:%M:%S'))
    #Adds the current x_limit_l value to the list

#After the loop ends, it finds the min value
x_limit_l = min(x_limit_list)

#If you want it in Hour, Min and Sec format:
x_limit_l = min(x_limit_list).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: Thank you! The code now throws the next fault:

TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not iterable

Can't I use a for-loop here?

Comment: The problem is not in the `for` loop. The error is showing because you are using `min` on `datetime` object. Check the edited section, if it works then.